# Acceleo Trasformation - Package with uri '*' not found.

Tags: code-generation, acceleo, mde

When I try do to an acceleo trasformation I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.impl.ResourceSetImpl$1DiagnosticWrappedException: org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi.PackageNotFoundException: Package with uri 'http://www.eclipse.org/mmt/qvtd/UmlToRdbms#rdbmsMM' not found. (file:/D:/Utenti/davi9/mde-workspace/Assignment2/Models/dummy.xmi, 7, 108)
    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.impl.ResourceSetImpl.handleDemandLoadException(ResourceSetImpl.java:319)
    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.impl.ResourceSetImpl.demandLoadHelper(ResourceSetImpl.java:278)
    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.impl.ResourceSetImpl.getResource(ResourceSetImpl.java:406)
    at org.eclipse.acceleo.common.utils.ModelUtils.load(ModelUtils.java:391)
    at org.eclipse.acceleo.common.utils.ModelUtils.load(ModelUtils.java:356)
    at org.eclipse.acceleo.engine.service.AbstractAcceleoGenerator.initialize(AbstractAcceleoGenerator.java:488)
    at org.eclipse.acceleo.module.sample.common.Generate.<init>(Generate.java:90)
    at org.eclipse.acceleo.module.sample.common.Generate.main(Generate.java:144)
Caused by: org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi.PackageNotFoundException: Package with uri 'http://www.eclipse.org/mmt/qvtd/UmlToRdbms#rdbmsMM' not found. (file:/D:/Utenti/davi9/mde-workspace/Assignment2/Models/dummy.xmi, 7, 108)
```

.....

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, I fixed it following this [solution](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Acceleo/FAQ#My_generation_fails_with_a_.27package_not_found.27_exception).

You need to register your package before loading your model.

I added this line:

```
EPackage.Registry.INSTANCE.put(XXXXPackage.eNS_URI, XXXXPackage.eINSTANCE);
```

in the method **registerPackages** of the java class **GeneratedHMTL.java** which I use for code generation with **XXXX** as the name of your model

I hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks for your help @QuentinCaspedes. At the end I solved this issue. I had a # character in the URI of my ecore model. Deleted this character it works